# HTML Email (Images Don't Always Display Correctly In Apple Mail)

Tags: html, image, email, apple-mail

I've been designing HTML emails for awhile now and recently came across an issue that I haven't seen posted anywhere online. I want to see if anyone else has encountered this.

**NOTE:** I’m using Apple Mail Version 9.3 on a MAC running OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.5

When I send out HTML formatted emails, the images aren’t always rendering correctly in Apple Mail. Instead of seeing the image or ALT text, I’ll see a thumbnail version of the email along with its filename. And, if I then reopen the email, I may see the images loading correctly or different images not loading correctly.

I've attached an example of a social media portion of an email I'm working on. You'll notice the Facebook icon isn't loading as an embedded image but rather, appears as a Thumbnail.

Since this issue only seems to occur in Apple Mail and doesn't happen all of the time, this is difficult to troubleshoot. Any help would be appreciated!

**HTML Code for the Social Media Portion of the Email**

NOTE: I am using absolute paths to the images. I didn't list the website URL in the code as a courtesy to my client. Let me know if this is enough code or if more is needed.

```html
<tr>
 <td align="right" bgcolor="#858789">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.website.com/Icon_Facebook_858789.png" alt="Facebook" style="padding:5px 5px 0 0"  width="25" height="25" border="0"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.website.com/Icon_Twitter_858789.png" alt="Twitter" style="padding:5px 5px 0 0"  width="25" height="25" border="0"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.website.com/Icon_YouTube_858789.png" alt="YouTube" style="padding:5px 5px 0 0"  width="25" height="25" border="0"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.website.com/Icon_LinkedIn_858789.png" alt="Linkedin" style="padding:5px 5px 0 0"  width="25" height="25" border="0"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.website.com/Icon_Instagram_858789.png" alt="Instagram" style="padding:5px 5px 0 0"  width="25" height="25" border="0"></a>
 </td>
</tr>
```

[image]

Comment: May we see the source of  the email ?

Comment: This isn't answerable without seeing some source code

Comment: I added the HTML code for the social media portion of the email.

Since this issue is only happening sometimes and may go away after reopening the email, I don't think it's an issue with the code. Has anyone encountered this particular issue where the image appears as a thumbnail in Apple Mail?